# Convergence of infinite sum (factorial and root)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms

Find the convergence of the following sequence:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{n!}{(2n)!}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
I tried to use the ratio test. It wasn't useful. Also I used the logharitmic test (I'm not sure this is the standard name for it): $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\ln\frac{1}{u_n}}{\ln n}=l$. If $l>1$,     $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n$ converges. It didn't work to well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you aware of strilings formula?

Comment: @tired: it seems that you are not the only one to know about this Strilings. http://show.docjava.com/cpe471/lectures/slides.htm/error_dt/tsld030.htm

Comment: No, "logharitmic" is not standard, though Google finds 885 instances.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - you may have confused him with that last comment. (Curiously, Google only found 880 instances for me - I feel cheated...). To explain: It is spelled "logarithmic", and yes that is the standard name for the test.

Answer (score 30):

$$\left(\frac{n!}{(2n)!}\right)^{1/n}=\left(\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n)}\right)^{1/n}>\left(\frac1{(2n)(2n)\cdots(2n)}\right)^{1/n}=\frac1{2n}$$

hence the series diverges.

Answer (score 16):

Using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation), you get
$$a_n=\left(\dfrac{n!}{(2n)!}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} \sim \left( \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}{\sqrt{4 \pi n}}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \left(\frac{e}{2n}\right)^{2n}\right)^{1/n}=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{1/n} \frac{e}{2n}$$

Hence the series diverges.